# how to make simple slider of image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

> i am try to make just simple slider of images

- images in img tag not a background image
- all images have display:none only first li have active class active class is display:block
- click on button add active class to only next one li and remove active from pre li
- i try but it active class add with all next li tag on click on button

```js
var btn_next = document.getElementById('next-btn');
btn_next.onclick = function() {
  if ($('#main_chagen li').hasClass('acitve') === true) {
    $('#main_chagen li.acitve').removeClass('acitve')
    $('#main_chagen li').next().addClass('acitve');
  } else {

  }
}
```

```css
.main_chagen {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#main_chagen img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#next-btn,
#pre-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15rem;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#next-btn {
  right: 0;
}

#pre-btn {
  left: 0;
}

#main_chagen li {
  display: none;
}

.img_acitve {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <ul id="main_chagen">
    <li class="acitve">
      <img src="1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="4.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="5.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button id="next-btn">next</button>
  <button id="pre-btn">pre</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added jQuery. Now add some images from placeholder.com

Comment: Why not use jQuery all the way? `$('#next-btn').on("click",function() {`

Comment: sir i used the $('#next-btn'). but  problem is that the active class add with all next li tag and i need to add only next one li tag on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

You will need to study it a bit

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on("click", function() {
    var $cur = $('#main_chagen li.active'); // possibly active
    var max = $('#main_chagen li').length;  // max number of LIs
    var dir = this.id.indexOf("next") === 0 ? 1:-1; // which button
    var idx = $cur.length === 0 ? 0 : $cur.index()+dir; // find the index of what we want to show
    if (idx >= max) idx = 0; // are we at end or beginning
    if (idx < 0) idx = max-1;
    $('#main_chagen li').removeClass("active").eq(idx).addClass("active");
  })
  $("#next-btn").click(); // show the first
});
```

```css
.main_chagen {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#main_chagen img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#next-btn,
#pre-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15rem;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#next-btn {
  right: 0;
}

#pre-btn {
  left: 0;
}

#main_chagen li {
  display: none;
}

li.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <ul id="main_chagen">
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/080808?text=2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/808080?text=3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FFFF/808080?text=4">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/AABBFF/808080?text=5">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button id="next-btn">next</button>
  <button id="pre-btn">pre</button>
</div>
```